# RobotFrameWork: Is there a way of checking the report.html although the run paused?

Tags: visual-studio-code, browser, report, robotframework

Situation: VisualStudioCode (Browser library) runs a couple of .robot files (manually started)
Then it pauses because of an error...

At that point the process breaks and there is no final report.html

If you stop the run it doesn't generate an report.html that's not what you want. You actually want the results until that point. (or even better described: you still want the links output.xml, log.html and report.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to generate lag.htm and report.html using the [rebot](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-rebot) command. however you need output.xml for this. output.xml is created when you run the tests. when you break you will probobaly not have all the resources you need.
I would suggest to assign [test timeout](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-case-timeout) to the test that causes the pause. When the timeout is reached the test will be stoped automaticaly and you should have all reports. You can also set it globaly for all tests eg.:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Timeout       2 minutes
```

Comment: Wauw that is really  GREAT @Jiri Janous  ! wish I could give you bounty haha. Maybe you can help me with the actual bounty question as well?

Comment: Hmmm... cheered a bit too soon maybe. It didn't work. Let me root cause this out hehe...

Comment: At first I thought ... aha, the Test Timeout  is not in the  resource file..., but then the message was:  'Timeout is not allowed in resource file'. hmmm that's ... okay hmmm...

Comment: You should put the test timeout to your testsuite not your resource file. Can you share some code? To better ilustrate your problem?